# How to get current locale with React-Native and i18n-js?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get current locale from the device of the user.
For now, I have 2 versions of my app : french and english.
It works fine when I change the fallback language I do have the two versions of the app.
But I can't manage to change the language directly from the device...

I used RNlocalize as seen in many pages but it doesn't work for me... my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import I18n from "./src/i18n/I18n";
import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";

async handleLocales() {
  this.locales = RNLocalize.getLocales();
}

getLocale() {
  if (this.locales) {
    if (Array.isArray(this.locales)) {
      return this.locales[0];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{I18n.t("hello")}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

My i18n.js file :

```
import I18n from "i18n-js";
import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";

import en from "./locales/en";
import fr from "./locales/fr";

const locales = RNLocalize.getLocales();

if (Array.isArray(locales)) {
  I18n.locale = locales[0].languageTag;
}

I18n.fallbacks = true;
I18n.translations = {
  en,
  fr
};

export default I18n;
```

I tried it in a test folder. The error I've got is

> ```
> SyntaxError: C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\App.js: Unexpected token, expected "=>" (5:19)
>
>   3 | import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";
>   4 | 
> > 5 | async handleLocales() {
>     |                    ^
>   6 |   this.locales = RNLocalize.getLocales();
>   7 | }
>   8 |
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I had something wrong in my locale.
Correcting this way everything works:

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import detector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { reactI18nextModule } from "react-i18next";
import { NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native';

import en from '../public/locales/en/translation.js';
import fr from '../public/locales/fr/translation.js';

// the translations
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: en
  },
  fr: {
    translation: fr
  }
};
const locale =
  Platform.OS === 'ios'
    ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale
    : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;
console.log(locale.substring(0, 2));
      i18n.locale = locale

i18n
  .use(detector)
  .use(reactI18nextModule) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: locale.substring(0, 2),
    fallbackLng: "en", // use en if detected lng is not available

    keySeparator: false, // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

Comment: can i use keySeparator in i18n-js(react native)? need to use flat json ("a.b.c") as key

Comment: I don't think you can use "i18next-browser-languagedetector" in a react native project, as it depends on browser functionality (e.g window.location.search)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
import { NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native';

const locale =
  Platform.OS === 'ios'
    ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale
    : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to answer me. Do I put this in my I18n file ? Or in the components ?

Comment: @Kimako You would need to get the the user's default locale as in the example and set that to your `I18n` `I18n.locale = locale` ...

Comment: Hey @HendEl-Sahli can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62290727/crash-app-in-rtl-devices-react-native-android) issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

AppleLocale can be undefined on ios when a fresh simulator is launched or if you have a device with a language but not a region.

So here is a workaround to get a locale if that is the case.

```
let locale = NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale // e.g. "fr_FR"
if (locale === undefined) {
    // iOS 13 workaround, take first of AppleLanguages array e.g. ["en", "en-NZ"]
    locale = NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0]
    if (locale == undefined) {
          locale = "en" // default language
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26540#issuecomment-535720033)